# using property-placeholder for in jar properties file

Tags: java, spring, jar

I use this line :

context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:resources/BLLresources/MQ.properties"

in a spring.xml file to look for MQ.properties which is inside the jar where the xml file is (in config folder at the root level).
I got error :

Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: {{uriMesarimReadQueue}} due to: Properties file classpath*:resources/BLLresources/MQ.properties not found in classpath

If I put the properties file outside the jar it works fine.

the jar is in the classpath.
any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your have your references setup incorrectly.  In a normal java project the resources folder would be located in `src/main/resources`, this folder gets mapped to the root of the generated jar file.  Therefore, if you had a file `src/main/resources/BLLresources/MQ.properties`, the mapping would be `classpath*:BLLresources/MQ.properties`